# Не отображается ответ cUrl

Tags: php, curl

Отсылаю запрос курлом на получение статистики но вардамп выдает пустую строку. Когда смотрю в курле контент тайп то пишет что текст\цсв. Техподдержка тоже говорит что мы вам ответ отсылаем в теле хттп ответа. Подскажите что нужно сделать что бы увидеть этот ответ (или записать его в БД или файл).

```
$ch = curl_init($url_stat);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response_stat = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($response_stat);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: вот что в заголовке присылает `string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: openresty
Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2016 13:25:27 GMT
Content-Type: text/csv
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

' (length=127)`

Comment: Почему вы смотрите в `$curl_getinfo` (не упомянутую в этом коде), тогда как результат `curl_exec` сохраняете в `$response_stat`?

Comment: сори осталось просто от просмотра на самом деле там стоит именно `$response_stat`

Comment: `var_dump` какую длину текста рапортует? Попробуйте воспроизвести через консольный curl

Comment: В подобных случаях я всегда запускаю wireshark/tcpdump и смотрю, что там по факту бегает.

Comment: `var_dump` говорит что string 0

Comment: wireshark/tcpdump что за зверь с чем едят? ок буду пробывать им что то посмотреть

Comment: это "сниффер". Вы увидите сетевую активность. И если в внутри wireshark Вы видите, что приходит пустой пакет, значит он пустой. И либо нужно исправлять запрос, либо искать, почему он стал пустой.